# Access JOI ref where key includes dot

Tags: joi

I am trying to do dependent validation based on a context option with a JOI schema.

```
let context = {
  "User.HasChildren": false,
}

let schema = Joi.object({
  "User.HasChildren": Joi.boolean(),
  "User.Children": Joi.when("$User.HasChildren", {
    is: true,
    then: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
    otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden()
  }),
  "User.ChildsYoungestAge": Joi.when("$User.HasChildren", {
    is: true,
    then: Joi.when("$User.Children", {
      is: Joi.number().min(0),
      then: Joi.number().required(),
      otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden()
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden()
  })
});

schema.validate({
    "User.HasChildren": true,
    "User.Children": 4,
    "User.ChildsYoungestAge": 4
  }, { context });
```

Basically the `.` in the key name is causing the failure. If I strip the `.` I get the expected result, but I have no control of the key name as it comes from an API response object.

I have attempted to change the separator in `options` but that did not work, how can I tell JOI that `.` is part of they ref/key?

Answer (score 0):

After additional analysis I realised I was on the right track but had not defined the separator correctly. Basically I tried setting it in the validate function but it needs to be defined individually to a ref.

```
let context = {
  "User.HasChildren": false,
}

let schema = Joi.object({
  "User.HasChildren": Joi.boolean(),
  "User.Children": Joi.when(Joi.ref("$User.HasChildren", { separator: false }), {
    is: true,
    then: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
    otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden()
  }),
  "User.ChildsYoungestAge": Joi.ref("$User.HasChildren", { separator: false }), {
    is: true,
    then: Joi.when(Joi.ref("$User.Children", { separator: false }), {
      is: Joi.number().min(0),
      then: Joi.number().required(),
      otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden()
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.any().forbidden()
  })
});

schema.validate({
    "User.HasChildren": true,
    "User.Children": 4,
    "User.ChildsYoungestAge": 4
  }, { context });
```